# Getting an internal server error while opening record from list view.(with Error Ids: 1563566187-9419 and 1563566187-9420)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, user-profile

When we click a record link in a standard list view that invokes our lightning aura component that calls our lightning web component to open the record in our record edit/view page,  that time we are getting enclosed/below internal error

When we put the debug log on the Apex side, that aura enabled method is getting invoked, but it is not executing any code. We have already verified Apex and Objects permission.

FYI please, For one profile it works fine and for another it is not working fine.  That is User a with different profile with the same permission set  it is working fine and for User b with different profile with same permission set it is not working.

Appreciate feedback/suggestions on this.

[image]

Debug Log:
[image]

Comment: Did you ensure that the profile has permission for that Apex class?

Comment: @sfdcfox, Yes, the profile has permissions to the apex class. 
Methods in apex class throw AuraHandledException.

Comment: Hmm. What about your debug logs? What's the last thing that executes before it crashes?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I have added debug log in the main post.

Comment: LWC calls multiple methods and all the methods are failing in a similar fashion.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with one of the parameters, perhaps. Make sure you're using the correct data types and case-sensitive parameter names.

Comment: Did you ensure/verify that the profile for User B has access to any objects, fields, etc. which might not be in the permission set that is the same for both users?

Comment: Also, have you tried temporarily changing User B to have the same profile as User A to see if it works for User B?  (And changing User A to have the same profile as the original User B profile to see if it does not work for User A?)

Comment: @sfdcfox, I have verified the parameter names and data types.

Comment: This package is installed in a number of orgs without a problem.

Comment: @Moonpie, All permissions required to access the objects and classes are in one permission set that is assigned to users with different profiles.

Comment: You didn't say whether you have tried temporarily changing User B to have the same profile as User A to see if it works for User B? (And changing User A to have the same profile as the original User B profile to see if it does not work for User A?).  That _should_ definitively rule in or out that the issue is in User B's profile.

Comment: @Moonpie  If we change User B profile to have the same profile of User A, it works fine.

Comment: And what about the inverse (or contrapositive or converse or Nike or whatever is the correct term): If you change User A to have the same profile that User B originally had?

Comment: Thanks, sfdcfox and Moonpie for your time. It was resolved with Spring 21 release.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved with Spring 21 release.